# Managing what is returned in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there a way to "silence" select statements inside a stored procedure as to not have a recordset returned for that particular statement?

As far as I know, each select statement inside a stored procedure will return a recordset.

Mainly, I have a some select statement used to initialize variables that could be skipped/silenced as to not return a recordset.

ie.

```
-- select team and set variable
select @team_id := id 
from table ...
```

**Edit #1**

Essentially, I think the question is about finding another way to initialize a variable with database data. Is this possible?

**Edit #2**

Here is the SP in question

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'admin'@'%'
PROCEDURE thebuggenie.cmdb_project_team_init(
  IN project_name VARCHAR(200), 
  IN project_key VARCHAR(200), 
  IN project_homepage VARCHAR(200), 
  IN team_name VARCHAR(200),
  OUT project_id INT(10))
BEGIN
  -- start transaction
  start transaction;

  -- init variables
  set @project_id = 0;
  set @team_id = 0;
  set @assoc_count = 0;
  set @scope_id = 1;

  -- select team and set variable
  select @team_id := id 
    from tbg3_teams 
    where name = team_name;

  -- if team_id = 0, insert team and set variable
  if @team_id is NULL or @team_id = '' or @team_id = 0 then
    -- insert new project
    insert into tbg3_teams(ondemand, name, scope) values(0, team_name, @scope_id);
    -- set team_id variable
    set @team_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  end if;

  -- select project and set variable
  select @project_id := id 
    from tbg3_projects 
    where name = project_name;

  -- if project_id = 0, insert project and set variable
  if @project_id is NULL or @project_id = '' or @project_id = 0 then
    -- insert project
    insert into tbg3_projects (name, locked, use_scrum, `key`, homepage, deleted, owner_team, scope, workflow_scheme_id, issuetype_scheme_id) values(project_name, 0, 1, project_key, project_homepage, 0, @team_id, @scope_id, 1, 1); 
    -- set project_id variable
    set @project_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  end if;

  select @assoc_count := count(*) 
    from tbg3_projectassignedteams 
    where uid = @team_id 
    and project_id = @project_id;

  if(@assoc_count = 0 and @project_id > 0 and @team_id > 0) then
    insert into tbg3_projectassignedteams (project_id, role_id, uid, scope) values(@project_id, 35, @team_id, @scope_id);
  end if;

  -- setup default views
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (101, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (102, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (110, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (105, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (106, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (111, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);

  commit;

  -- return values
  select @project_id into project_id;
END
```

Comment: If you don't want anything returned, simply don't use a `SELECT`. It appears you're not doing something right. How about explaining your *entire* goal instead of focusing on a part of the thing you're trying to do? This is a clear XY problem.

Comment: @n-b I only posted a portion of the logic. Most of the selects are to initialize variables, then use those variables in conditional statements and finally, actually select data based on those variables.

Comment: You're telling us *how* you want to achieve something. Not what that something *is*. Therefore, the only thing you can get as an answer is a **no, you can't silence a SELECT**. Since we're absolutely in the dark to what you're doing and why you need to even initialize variables, all that's left here is to say good luck, unless you decide to share your entire logic and goal with us so we can discuss it and come up with a final solution that works by the book.

Comment: @n-b Added the SP in my second edit. Essentially, I don't think it's possible to initialize variables from database data without making select statements?

Comment: That's correct. You can't get anything from the database without using a `SELECT` (with the exception of `SHOW`). What you could do is initialize a variable to a hardcoded value if a session variable is set to a certain value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to "silence" select statements within a stored procedure. Every select will return a recordset and it's required to use a select to initalize a variable with data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You mean other than by conditionally executing that select statement based on the value of a Stored proc parameter?

```
 Create procedure MyProc
 @includeEmployeeData bit = 1
 as

     Select [Stuff]
     From OneTable

     if @includeEmployeeData = 1
         Select [EmployeeStuff]
         From employees ...

     Select [Stuff]
     From SomeOtherTable
```

Comment: actually, it's more like being able to have a select not return anything back other than setting the value of the variable. Maybe, it's just that, finding an alternative to initializing needed variables.

Comment: I am not intimately familiar with mySQL.  Are you saying that in MySQL, stored procs, executing a select statement whose select clause only has variable assignments returns a resultset to the client code?  This is NOT the case with other RDBMSs.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I understand it and seems to be the way it works.

Comment: That really surprises me.  If true, it would be a serious design flaw.  If I had access to MySQL I would test it myself, but if I were you, I would test it to validate that your understanding is correct.

Comment: manually running my query in DBForge for instance, yields 4 results sets based on the SP posted in my OP.